# What does the column flag "G" in MySQL Workbench mean

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, mysql-workbench, database-schema

See the image below, but as part of the table editor, there's column flags such as PK (primary key), NN (not null) and so on.  The last one is 'G'
[image: MySQL table editor image]

Comment: What workbench version?

Comment: Not as such as there: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/workbench-faq.html#faq-workbench-column-acronyms

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having looked through some of the Workbench code and the MySQL documentation, it looks like the G column is for [Generated Columns](http://mysqlserverteam.com/generated-columns-in-mysql-5-7-5/).

In the source code, there's the following within the [mysql_table_editor_column_page](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-workbench/blob/aa9272c882eb9305f67890d177d70821cb5d28b3/plugins/db.mysql.editors/linux/mysql_table_editor_column_page.cpp) file (line 132 at the time of writing):

```
model->model().append_check_column(MySQLTableColumnsListBE::IsGenerated, "G", EDITABLE);
```

Other code in the same area gives the layout consistent with what you're seeing in the visual for PK, NN etc., which is viewable in the source.

Comment: Thank you, this new column type will be added to the documentation.